# Load app bundle only after login

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have an application that uses Auth0 for authentication. I would like to load the application bundle only after the user has been authenticated so that no unauthorised user can see the actual JavaScript bundle and look at some of our proprietary business logic. The application is has been created using create-react-app and is deployed on Heroku.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you have proprietary business logic in the frontend?

Comment: @Webbanditten Its not really business logic. Its just that we'd prefer unauthorized users not to be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can code split your bundle to `auth` and `app` with https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/, in this way authorization logic will use only necessary components needed to render auth page, and after that it will just lazy load everything else

Comment: I've done this, but a malicious user can still look through the routes in the base bundle and figure out the path to the app chunk.

Comment: Then only option is to serve 2 apps on different endpoints, add authentication on backend level and respond 403 on every asset when user is not logged in, after authorization you will redirect to 2nd app with cookies/token with authorization.