# How do I entirely limit access from a frontend framework(react) to specific(admin) pages using REST API(is it possible?)

Tags: reactjs, rest

I'm very new to REST API and frontend JS frameworks world, and I don't really understand how I can limit access for a frontend to specific pages, I don't really think I can, am I? I'll explain:

Usually, if I develop without REST API, I can use backend to determine if a user may access content(on some pages) and block it if needed, so there's no possible way to download(and view) whatever it might/could be presented on that page.

On the other hand, if I make REST API for the same pages, I can only limit the presented data(I will basically block any request to certain protected endpoint), but yet, the user still will be able to download the schema of the page(frontend part), even I will check if user can/can't view the page, still he will be able to download it and see it, because, well... I check it in frontend and all the logic to present the data is also in frontend(that user may see, even though through a code).

Am I getting this right, if not please explain it to me.

Comment: Hello @fevlt8. Welcome to SO! The question is pretty broad. Try scoping it down with a specific essential example and you'll get a better answer. (Create public component and admin component, share the code, and then explain what should happen.) Your current question is likely to draw opinions and theory instead of concrete answers. An approach that may work is to split the client into two parts. Lazy load the admin part if the user is authenticated and poses the correct role.

Comment: See if [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense) about code splitting in the React docs helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm talking about. If I suspense and then import component conditionally, and even if I'll check inside the same component round directly for a condition(if admin), the client still will be able to download it(because it's frontend) and view it, even if in code only, but still. Or is it not true?

Comment: Check out the second comment in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911351/3105371. Basically, you need to serve a separate admin app which requires credentials in the request for all assets on the endpoint serving the admin app. If you want to share components between the public and the admin apps, make a third package to create a common component library.

Comment: I don't really see how it will solve the issue, tbh. Sure, I can(and will) check for every request for any assets or any other data, but it will happen on the server at the endpoint. Not at the frontend. So, not matter what I do(code splitting or separate app), it(frontend part) still will be accessible to everyone. I mean, it's not crucial if there's no data, I guess... but yet, it sounds very odd to someone like me, who used to code it in a more "hidden" way

Comment: The endpoint serving the admin client should respond with an error if auth token isn't included with the request. So the admin client wouldn't be exposed. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, the admin client will respond with an error and might redirect you and what not, but it's on the client. Client can do whatever he want. I can control(like really control) only the backend response at that point, and the client will still have the code (even if it's pseudo controlled with `if (!jwt.isAdmin) return`. I guess I can't truly hide it after all

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough before. The bundle with all client side react code for admin won't be served unless the request has a valid token (in query string or cookie). So an unauthorized user won't be able to see the admin client or obtain it in the first place. The guard is enforced on the server side, not client. (Well, client too, but just for good ux.)

Comment: So the login page won't be a react app? Is that what you're saying? And yet, even if so, I still need to provide a bundle file to a user... authorized or not. and it's still a client side... so what's the point in that?